# Laravel 4 PHPUnit Sqlite Database, delete items before every test

Tags: sqlite, laravel, phpunit, laravel-4

I have a Laravel 4 application with sqlite db configured for testing.

I am working in a workbench package

I have a problem testing my models in a PHPUnit Test, because i defined some unique properties on my model. I run `Artisan::call('migrate', array('--bench' => 'vendor/webshop'));` from my Basic Test Class from which i extend other Tests.

I think this runs the database migrations, but in my opinion it does not delete the models in the database.

Because if i do

```
public function setUp() {

    parent::setUp();

    $this->order = Order::create(array(
        "uniquekey" = "123"
    ));
}
```

I get an error saying, can not insert model because of violation of unique key rule.

How should i clean the database before every test?

Comment: i am simply deleting my model by doing `$this->order->forceDelete();`, but this is not a really solution to the problem

Answer (score 3):

You should define environment for testing purposes.

Actually Laravel does have one for you - notice `testing` folder inside your `app/config`.

Create `app/config/testing/database.php` (or modify if exists) and place this:

```
return array(

    'default' => 'sqlite',

    'connections' => array(

        'sqlite' => array(
            'driver'   => 'sqlite',
            'database' => ':memory:', // this will do the trick ;)
            'prefix'   => '',
        ),
    ),
);
```

When you run tests, Laravel sets it's environment to 'testing' automaticaly - no need to play with this.
SQLite in-memory DB is memory stored withing RAM, thus it's fast - and yes, tests start with empty database as well.

Comment: as i mentioned in the first line i am already doing this, but the database is only cleared for each Class, not for each test, i guess

Comment: there is no option to `migrate:refresh` as discussed here : https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1267#issuecomment-21468659